# Glade Designer is crashing

Tags: apt, gtk3, glade

Here is the Error I am facing. I really need to get Glade up and running please help.

I used the command

```
sudo apt-get install glade
```

And this is what I got when trying to run Glade designer

```
nirvasi@nirvasiTerminal:~$ glade
GladeUI-Message: 20 missing displayable value for GtkWidget::AtkObject::accessible-role
GladeUI-Message: 1 missing displayable value for GtkCellRendererAccel::accel-mode
GladeUI-Message: Glade needs artwork; a default icon will be used for the following classes:
    GtkApplicationWindow    needs an icon named 'widget-gtk-applicationwindow'

(glade:2331): Gtk-WARNING **: Unknown property: GtkBox.margin-end

(glade:2331): Gtk-WARNING **: Unknown property: GtkBox.margin-end
glade: symbol lookup error: glade: undefined symbol: gtk_widget_set_margin_start
nirvasi@nirvasiTerminal:~$
```

Before this I was trying to install some libraries to build from source the lastest version of Glade. And I "sudo make install"ed quite a few packages. Could they be the reason this error is occuring?

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using?  What version of gtk are you using? e.g. are you using ubuntu 15.10 with gtk version 3.16 or gtk version 3.18 from a PPA?

Answer (score 2):

I found what was wrong. I had previously tried to build from source the latest version of Glade 3.18.3. But that required my gtk to be be 3.12.0 . But my gtk was 3.10.0 and that seemed to be the latest version acquirable through apt-get install. So I downloaded the source of the actual latest version 3.12.2 and built that from source and executed a make install statement on it.

However the glade 3.18.3 source still wouldn't build. So... There it was. So I gave up on it and thought what if `sudo apt-get install glade` would work ?

And it was after this that I tried to run glade from the applications menu and the Error I mentioned in the question here happened to me.

So anyway, I did a

```
sudo make uninstall
```

in the source directory of the gtk 3.12.2 . Lo and behold it worked. It uninstalled everything I had installed and now Glade is working.

I'm using ubuntu MATE 14.04 btw.